# c++ MFC interface to SQL database

Tags: c++, sql, mfc, odbc

I have an application written in c++ with MFC. It uses Recordset and ODBC to communicate with SQL database.

From visual studio, I usually create class for each table/view I need through class wizard tool. Starting from Visual Studio 2019 I don't find "MFC ODBC Consumer" from drop down list, so I suppose Recorset got outdated, so my question is: which technology is the most up to date to allow a c++ application to communicate with an SQL database?

Here attached image from VS2017 where I have "MFC ODBC Consumer" and from VS2019 where I have not.
[VS2017](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JKr8p.png)
[VS2019](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cIlG4.png)

Comment: The MFC ODBC Consumer [has been removed starting with Visual Studio 2019](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/mfc-odbc-consumer-wizard?view=msvc-160). Your options are `1` manually implement the adapters, or `2` open the project in Visual Studio 2017, have the Class Wizard do its magic, and move back to Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but my real question is the following:

Is there something better/newer than Recordset?

Comment: There is no newer `CRecordSet` in the MFC (why would there need to be?). I don't know what *"better"* means to you. If by *"better"* you mean *"comes with a wizard that generates code I don't understand"*, then no, there is nothing *"better"* in the MFC either. I have presented the options in my previous comment. If neither of those options suit your needs, pick a non-MFC database adapter library/framework.

Comment: I suppose Recordset got outdated because I don't find the wizard in VS2019. As you suggest in your first comment, I already use older VS to use the wizard to create Recordset Class.
thanks for your time

Comment: MFC wizards come and MFC wizards go. I have long stopped relying on them for anything. Whenever *I* need to write MFC code, I just write the code. Just get yourself a copy of Jeff Prosise' [Programming Windows with MFC](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B012HU5KPA) and you no longer need to rely on *any* wizards. The book is somewhat dated, though Amazon's claim that it were published on January 1st, 1600 isn't actually true.